# Endless/Infinite Scrolling not working for gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, gson, retrofit, infinite-scroll

My app tries to get various information from an api call using Retrofit and Gson. This information needs to be displayed as a gridview and the gridview needs to repopulate on scrolling. As of now, I can get the first 10 items, and thats it. How to add the endless scrolling feature to this.

public class ProductListing extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_listing_act);
    init();
}

public void productListingApiCall() {

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(base_url).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
    final ProductListingApi productListingApi =
            restAdapter.create(ProductListingApi.class);
    productListingApi.getFeed(file, operation_condition, search_string_condition, minprice_condition, maxprice_condition, mincusratings_condition,
            maxcusratings_condition, discount_condition, catids_condition, brands_condition, affids_condition, start_row_condition, limit_condition,
            orderby_condition, sortby_condition, new Callback<ProductListingPojo>() {

                @Override
                public void success(ProductListingPojo productListingPojo, Response response) {
                    final ProductListingPojo product = productListingPojo;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            product_key = Arrays.copyOf(product.getProductkey(),
                                    product.getProductkey().length);
                            cs_category_id = Arrays.copyOf(product.getCsCategoryid(),
                                    product.getCsCategoryid().length);
                            title = Arrays.copyOf(product.getTitle(),
                                    product.getTitle().length);
                            price = Arrays.copyOf(product.getSellingprice(),
                                    product.getSellingprice().length);
                            mrp = Arrays.copyOf(product.getMrp(),
                                    product.getMrp().length);
                            discount = Arrays.copyOf(product.getDiscountpercent(),
                                    product.getDiscountpercent().length);
                            image = Arrays.copyOf(product.getProductimageSmall1(),
                                    product.getProductimageSmall1().length);
                            cus_agg_num = Arrays.copyOf(product.getCustratingAggNum(),
                                    product.getCustratingAggNum().length);

                        }
                    }).run();

                    setAdapter();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv_title_header.setText(error.getMessage());
                    Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
                }
            });
}

void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new ProductListingGridAdapter(this, title, image, price, mrp, discount);
    gv_product_listing_act.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

The init() in OnCreate() will initialise all the view and call the productListingApiCall() for the first time. The way the api works is that, i will request for the first 10 items (start_row_condition: 0 and limit: 10), then on reaching the bottom after scrolling it should add the next 10, hence i need to call the api with (start_row_condition: 10 and limit:10). How can i implement this.